# Multiple value conversions in one field in Access 2016

Tags: type-conversion, relationship, ms-access-2016

I have a database of NYC real estate properties that utilizes the BBL ([Borough, Block, Lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borough,_Block_and_Lot)) system.

The format of the first table is `1/9999/9999999`, where the first number is the borough, the second series of numbers is the block, and the third series of numbers is the lot. In this format, in the first number of the series, 1 is Manhattan, 2 is Bronx, 3 is Brooklyn, 4 is Queens, and 5 is Staten Island.

The format of the second table is text, as follows:

```
Borough    Block      Lot
MANHATTAN  0033   1085971
MANHATTAN  0033   1085971
MANHATTAN  0033   1064871
MANHATTAN  0033   1030178
```

How can I convert five different Borough values into five different integer values in the same field so that I can create a relationship between the two tables based on a common BBL field? I would rather not do a nested `IIF` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Left* to extract the borough id from the BBL code, then *Choose* to select the name:

```
Borough: Choose(Left([BBL], 1), "Manhattan", "Bronx", "Brooklyn", "Queens", "Staten Island")
```